# react-native sentence and word questions for the function

Tags: react-native

this might be a dumb question, but I am trying to learn react-native, but since I am new to programming, I just dont understand each sentences and how it works. Could anyone explain to me every each sentences and word that what is going on and how it works? I looked it up and I sort of understand but still I am very confused...This is the code that I am trying to understand right now. I just dont understand renderChildren() function part...

```
var SliderContainer = React.createClass({

getInitialState() {
return {
  value: DEFAULT_VALUE,
};
},

render() {
var value = this.state.value;

return (
  <View>
  <Text style={{fontSize:15, fontFamily:'Bradley Hand'}}> Distortion </Text>

    {this.renderChildren()}
  </View>
);
},

renderChildren() {
return React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
  if (child.type === Slider
      || child.type === ReactNative.Slider) {
    var value = this.state.value;
    return React.cloneElement(child, {
      value: value,
      onValueChange: (val) => this.setState({value: val}),
    });
  } else {
    return child;
  }
});
},
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So in the render function

```

```
return (
  <View>
  <Text style={{fontSize:15, fontFamily:'Bradley Hand'}}> Distortion </Text>

    {this.renderChildren()}
  </View>
);
```

```

Answer (score 0):

So in the render function

```
return (
  <View>
    <Text style={{fontSize:15, fontFamily:'Bradley Hand'}}> Distortion </Text>

    {this.renderChildren()}
  </View>
);
```

The `{this.renderChildren()}` is just a function call which runs this code...

```
renderChildren() {
return React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
  if (child.type === Slider
      || child.type === ReactNative.Slider) {
    var value = this.state.value;
    return React.cloneElement(child, {
      value: value,
      onValueChange: (val) => this.setState({value: val}),
    });
  } else {
    return child;
  }
});
},
```

Comment: React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) =>    and,  onValueChange: (val) => this.setState({value: val})